# Remove <li> indentation

Tags: html, css

I've removed the bullet on my lists using

```
ul li { list-style: none; }
```

But I'm still getting an indentation on the lists as if the bullet was there.

[image]

I need the list-item in the image to be exactly centered.

Comment: why the downvote?  Seems like a fine question to me

Comment: Probably downvoted for lack of effort (did they try looking at the margin/padding of the element in question?).

Comment: There's dozens of Related links with basically the same question -->

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Browsers ship a default styling attached to `<ul/>` and `<li/>` tags

```
ul,li { list-style-type: none;
        list-style-position:inside;
        margin:0;
        padding:0; }
```

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 2):

All the answers provided will fix your issue, but I definately recommend that you look in to using a reset stylesheet so you don't have cross browser issues!

The best one (well most popular one at least), is most likely this:

http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/

Hope that helps your issue, but if you don't want to use a reset style sheet simply:

```
ul, li{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also add a margin and padding 0:

```
ul li { 
   list-style: none; 
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to center the text, try

```
li{ 
  padding-left: 0px; 
  padding-right:0px; 
  margin-left:0px; 
  margin-right:0px; 
  text-align:center;
}
```