# How to vertically conditionally align to the middle a li inside an ul

Tags: html, css

I have the following template:

```
<ul>
<li class="show-large-placeholder">
    <img ....>
</li>
```

I am trying to align this list item in the center of the UL, I don't have access to changes of style for the ul, because the class show-large-preview on the li is conditionally added, so seeing display table won't work here.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this of any use? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426609/remove-li-indentation Try stylizing the `li` element to have centered indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your own `id` element to the `li`, like so:

```html
<ul>
<li id="center-li" class="show-large-placeholder">
    <img ...>
</li>
```

Then, you can apply css to that `id`, instead of the whole `class`:

```css
center-li {
    /* Add your css here */
}
```

That should do it.